# How to change the string in data frame to integer ID with pandas fast?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set including the `user ID`, `item ID`(both string) and rating like that:

```
A12VH45Q3H5R5I B000NWJTKW 5.0
A3J8AQWNNI3WSN B000NWJTKW 4.0
A1XOBWIL4MILVM B000NWJTKW 1.0
```

I'd like to change the `ID`s to integer like:

```
1              1          5.0
2              1          4.0
3              1          1.0
```

I have tried a traditional way, creating a big dictionary and mark each string ID with an integer one. But it took extremely long time. So could you please tell me how to finish it in a more fast way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `apply` [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html#pandas.Series.factorize):

```
In [244]:
df[[0,1]] = df[[0,1]].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)
df

Out[244]:
   0  1  2
0  1  1  5
1  2  1  4
2  3  1  1
```

Comment: And I also wonder can i get the number of users and items in a similar way?

Comment: Are you asking for `df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)`?

Comment: Indeed, what I mean is the number of users instead of the number of occurrence of users. I'd like to know how many unique users in the data set.

Answer (score 3):

You could also encode the column as a [categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#object-creation) and then get the codes.

```
df['User_ID_code'] = df.User_ID.astype('category').cat.codes
>>> df
          User_ID     Item_ID  Rating  User_ID_code
0  A12VH45Q3H5R5I  B000NWJTKW       5             0
1  A3J8AQWNNI3WSN  B000NWJTKW       4             2
2  A1XOBWIL4MILVM  B000NWJTKW       1             1
```

Comment: Does it assign the same User_ID_code to the same User_ID each time?